# WhatsApp audio media message (MediaUrl0) Transcribe to text

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, chatbot, whatsapp, voice-recognition

I have a dialogflow chatbot that communicates with Whatsapp for business users, thru Twilio.

I would like to enhance the "chat" chatbot capability, and allow whatsapp users to also be able to send a voice messages.

WhatsApp voice media messages sent to Twilio have a URI parameter with the location of the media file, but this URI does not have a file extension. How can i extract the file to send it to a Speech-to-text service (Google or AWS) to have it transcribed into text and then send it to Dialogflow for intent recognition

Any ideas how i would go about doing this?

Twilio message log for a media message:

```
    Request Inspector
    + Expand All
    POST
    https://xxxxxxxxxxxx
    2021-04-27 08:35:39 UTC502
    Request
    URL
    ParametersShow Raw
    MediaContentType0   "audio/ogg"
    SmsMessageSid   "MMea4e6bcb3a9654a03d8d2a607c6d4cdd"
    NumMedia    "1"
    ProfileName "xxxxx"
    SmsSid  "MMea4e6bcb3a9654a03d8d2a607c6d4cdd"
    WaId    "xxxxxxxxx"
    SmsStatus   "received"
    Body    ""
    To  "whatsapp:+32460237475"
    NumSegments "1"
    MessageSid  "MMea4e6bcb3a9654a03d8d2a607c6d4cdd"
    AccountSid  "ACef27744806d8f8e68f25211b2ba8af60"
    From    "whatsapp:+32474317098"
    MediaUrl0   "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACef27744806d8f8e68f25211b2ba8af60/Messages/MMea4e6bcb3a9654a03d8d2a607c6d4cdd/Media/ME27fbc66d47d8de49f1ae00e433884097"
    ApiVersion  "2010-04-01"
    Message TextShow Raw
    sourceComponent "14100"
    httpResponse    "502"
    url "https://xxxxxxxxx"
    ErrorCode   "11200"
    LogLevel    "ERROR"
    Msg "Bad Gateway"
    EmailNotification   "false"
```

Comment: This question is too broad. You should break down the problem into its component parts and attempt to solve each separately. Once you have figured out the more specific part that you're having a problem with, you can come back and ask a more specific question about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the extension for this use case, you will probably need the language code for the resulting text and may be, AudioEncoding and sample rating for the transcription service.

Here is some examples from my code for whatson / google coud speech to text and DialogFlow.. AWS and Microsoft are very similar

```
//for ibm watson
RecognizeOptions recognizeOptions = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
     .model(RecognizeOptions.Model.ES_ES_NARROWBANDMODEL)
     .audio(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
     .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)
     .build();

// google speech to text
RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
     .setSampleRateHertz(48000)
     .setLanguageCode(langcode)
     .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.OGG_OPUS)
     .build();

// Dialogflow (sending audio directly)
 InputAudioConfig inputAudioConfig = InputAudioConfig
     .newBuilder()
     .setLanguageCode(langcode)
     .setSampleRateHertz(sampleRateHertz)
     .build();
```

In the end, in all cases, what you send to the service is not a file but an array of byte (sort of)

Anyway, even when there is no one to one relation between content Type and file extension, the parameter "MediaContentType0" in the request give you a good starting point: "audio/ogg".